# Android navigation component huge space in toolbar

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-navigation

I've configured a toolbar with a navigation drawer using the new android component architecture

Layout is as follows:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        android:background="@color/actionBar_background">

        <fragment
            android:name="ToolbarLogoFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/actionBar_Logo"/>

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

    <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_root"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/activity_background"
        tools:openDrawer="start">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
                android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                app:defaultNavHost="true"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:navGraph="@navigation/main_nav_graph"/>

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/main_menu_width"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:background="@color/actionBar_background"
            android:paddingStart="@dimen/menu_item_padding_start"
            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/menu_item_padding_start"
            app:itemBackground="@drawable/drawable_item"
            app:itemIconTint="@color/drawable_item"
            app:itemTextAppearance="@style/item_menu_style"
            app:itemTextColor="@color/drawable_item"
            app:menu="@menu/main_menu"/>

    </androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And the setup code is straight forward:

```
private fun setupToolbar() {
    val appbarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(setOf(R.id.landing_dest), drawer_root)
    toolbar.setupWithNavController(navController, appbarConfiguration)
}
```

All works almost great, except there is a huge gap between the navigation drawer and the custom logo I have on my toolbar and I am not user where is is coming from.

Using layout inspector I can see I only have 2 components in my toolbar

[image]

My custom logo and the drawer button

This is how it looks on the view.

[image]

I have absolutely no margins or padding on my layout, without the actions bar toggle button the logo will show right on the left margin.

Where does the gap between the button and the layout come from?

Answer (score 0):

Ended up fixing it with:

```
            app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
            app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
            app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp">
```